# How to update the price of a product based on the birth date of the registrant

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a content type EVENT with the event date field,

I created products with various attributes (ENTIRE - UNDER - FEMALE, etc ..)

Each attribute generates a different price for the product.

```
Product1 -> ENTIRE = € 10 - 
Product1 -> UNDER € 8

Product2 -> ENTIRE = € 15 - 
Product2 -> UNDER € 5
```

Now, in registration ([COMMERCE REGISTRATION](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_registration)) checkout, insert the birth  date of a user. I must compare birth date with event date. If the user is a minor pays UNDER, otherwise ENTIRE.

Comment: Any suggestion?